# How to use Guid without alphabet (selenium c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

I am new to testing, I have to fill the register number and I have to use the same register number for another operation too. Unfortunately not possible to use any alphabets, only numbers.

My Testing code is (Note: No alphabetic characters allowed):

```
var RegisterNo = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
editCasePage.FillRegisterNrTextbox(RegisterNo);
```

I have to use same RegisterNumber here:

```
editcasePageObject.FillRegisterNoCheck(RegisterNo);
```

Comment: Does it have to be unique? Does it have to be in order? Then you could simply use a counter variable. Do you store all numbers in memory?

Comment: @TimSchmelter  RegisterTextBox allows to enter only numbers

Comment: so you answer none of my questions?

Comment: @TimSchmelter   it has to be unique, I didn't store numbers in memory

Comment: So where do you store them? If it's in a database, why don't you let the database generate this number because it's the only place where this can be checked?

Comment: I have to use random numbers but every time should be different,If i run the test it's enters the registerNumber and recheck the registerNumber not to be same for each testing.Instead of guid How can i use random number generater here?!

Comment: No, I didn't linked,Because no database needed i am testing website.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's a website , first page is a add item page im entering random register number and after clicked on save.it moves to next page there  uses the  same register number to filter my item using same register number. I Hope you understand my question :)

Comment: If you need an integer, maybe this is unique enough(it is not ofc): `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()`. But instead i would use the `Guid`. I dont get why you cant use any string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  It works Man. Dankeschön:), Small problem when it's reenter the same number with dash like this  -604934080,i need without dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, even if i don't think this is a reliable solution (because the result is not unique and can produce collisions). Maybe you can use it anyway to get pseudo-random, pseudo-unique integers:

```
public static int GetTempRegisterNumber()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
}
```

But i don't understand why you can't use the `Guid` itself. That would be a much better approach.

Comment: But it returns the same value with dash

Comment: @MutuArron: it generates integers, there are no dashs. You mean the minus sign in front?

Comment: If you need positive integers collisions are even more likely. You can get it with: `return Math.Abs(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a set of numbers from a guid, you could do this:

```
public static int GuidToNumbers(string guid)
{
    var numbers = guid.GetHashCode();
    return numbers < 0 ? numbers * -1 : numbers;
}
```

And use it like:

```
GuidToNumbers(RegisterNo);
```

Comment: I am sending registerNo using cssselector.sendkeys(), so it will not work by this method , can you try any alternative answer

Comment: Why do you think it will not work? You can pass the result of this method to your `FillRegisterNrTextBox` method like so: `editCasePage.FillRegisterNrTextbox(GuidToNumbers(RegisterNo));`

Answer (score 0):

How many distinct numbers do you need?  Is it possible that you can use numbers that only seem random to the test, and instead build something that produces a number that fits a test case but mixes it up a little?

Incidentally, for most automated tests, it's recommended that you do not use random numbers as input values.  One of the principles behind automated testing is repeatability, and if one number passes and another fails, it's easy to lose track of what the failure case was.  If all numbers of a specific format will be treated equally, there's not much purpose in mixing them up too much unless you want to test edge cases, and in that case you should test the edge cases specifically - making sure that filling the fields with "8"s doesn't overflow your text box for a variable-width font, or something.

Personally, if I want to hammer it hard (and I often do), I usually test my minimum allowed value, my maximum allowed value, make sure that minimum-1 breaks or is disallowed as expected, make sure that maximum+1 breaks or is disallowed, test my zero case if it's not the minimum, test a one-digit number, test a maximal-digit non-maximum number, and throw a smattering of medium- and long-length numbers in, too.  But I hand-pick these values and they're the same at every execution.

If you really need the randomness, is a predictable randomness okay?

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] values = 
{
    random.Next(0,9),
    random.Next(11,19),
    random.Next(100,999),
    random.Next(1000,9999)
};
    Something like that that allows you to draw each number from pools wherein the pools simply don't overlap?
```

There's really not a good way that I know of to guarantee uniqueness in anything but a GUID without either storing state and regenerating or modifying a new number if it's already been used, or specifying the values manually or procedurally.  But if you manipulate the GUID, like hashing it or removing alphabetic characters from the result, you're liable to introduce collisions that you'll only notice when it occasionally collides and you have no idea why it's failing, unless you use a non-colliding hash function.